# Cannot retrieve customer table information

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2003

Here are the sample code for my application which only retrieve the ID's from the customer Table but however do not retrieve the related information when clicked on the customerIDListBox to view customer information.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    OleDbConnection dbConn;

    private void ConnectToDatabase()
    {
        //initialise the connection
        dbConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
        User Id=;
        Password=;
        Data Source=DMarx v1.0.mdb");

        //open connection
        dbConn.Open();
    }

   /* private void DisconnectFromDatabase()
    *{
    *   dbConn.Close();
    *}
    */
    private OleDbDataReader ExecuteQuery(string query)
    {
        /*
         * try...catch because ExecuteReader can throw an exception
         * if the query is incorrect, or if the database has not yet been connected
         */
        try
        {
            //create the command object
            OleDbCommand cmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
            //assign the query to it
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            //execute the command
            return cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch (OleDbException)
        {
            //if an exception ocurrs, return nothing
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //connect to the database
        ConnectToDatabase();

        //select all the customer id's from the database
        string query = "SELECT ID FROM Customer;";
        OleDbDataReader dbReader = ExecuteQuery(query);

        //if any rows were returned
        if (dbReader != null && dbReader.HasRows)
        {
            //dbReader.Read() will return true until there are 
            //no more rows to be read
            while (dbReader.Read())
            {
                customerIDListBox.Items.Add(dbReader["ID"]);
            }
        }

        //we are finished with the database for now, disconnect
      //  DisconnectFromDatabase();
    }

    private void customerIDListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConnectToDatabase();

        //construct the query string 
        string queryString = "SELECT Name, Surname, TelNo FROM";
        queryString = queryString + "Customer WHERE ID = " + customerIDListBox.SelectedItem + ";";

        //execute the query
        OleDbDataReader dbReader = ExecuteQuery(queryString);

        //if we have results
        if (dbReader != null && dbReader.HasRows)
        {
            //we are only expecting one row, so it is not neccessary to iterate through the results
            dbReader.Read();
            nameTextBox.Text = dbReader["Name"].ToString();
            surnameTextBox.Text = dbReader["Surname"].ToString();
            telephoneNumberBox.Text = dbReader["TelNo"].ToString();
        }

        //now to get the clients accounts
        queryString = "SELECT Id, AccountType, Balance FROM Account WHERE ClientId = ";
        queryString = queryString + customerIDListBox.SelectedItem + ";";

        //clear the accounts list (so that only the currently selected client's accounts are shown)
        accountsListBox.Items.Clear();

        //execute the query
        if (dbReader != null && dbReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (dbReader.Read())
            {
                //construct a string with the details
                String accountDetails = dbReader["Id"] + " - ";
                accountDetails = accountDetails + dbReader["AccountType"] + " - ";
                accountDetails = accountDetails + dbReader["Balance"];

                //add the string to the accounts list box
                accountsListBox.Items.Add(accountDetails);
            }
        }

      //  DisconnectFromDatabase();

    }

    private void saveChangesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //make sure the use has selected something before clicking the button
        if (customerIDListBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            ConnectToDatabase();

            //create the query
            String queryString = "UPDATE Customer SET Name = '" + nameTextBox.Text + "', Surname = '";
            queryString = queryString + surnameTextBox.Text + "', TelNo= '";
            queryString = queryString + telephoneNumberBox.Text + "'";
            queryString = queryString + " WHERE Id = " + customerIDListBox.SelectedItem + ";";

            ExecuteQuery(queryString);

        //    DisconnectFromDatabase();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a customer first!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging your application? Are there any exceptions thrown (hidden with code in your `try...catch` blocks)? Try stepping through the code and chreking what is going on.

Based on the information provided I can think of two possible causes for the error:

- `customerIDListBox_SelectedIndexChanged` not being actually added as a handler to the `SelectedIndexChanged` and therefore not being called when you click on the listbox
- `ExecuteQuery` might throw an exception for your query - in this case your code quietly does nothing

Comment: When i constructed the code in the customerIDListBox_SelectedIndexChanged, i just double clicked the list box, isnt that suppose to add the handler automatically?

Comment: @user3350153 Yes, in this case the handler was attached. If really no exceptions occur at runtime, then your best bet is to step through the code line by line nad check what the query returns. BTW, why did you remove your sample code?

Comment: sorry im new to this, will add it back now. Signed up a few minutes ago.

Comment: I added the code back, do you think it will help if i recoded the application? and can it be that the compiler stored irrelevant data that i might have added and deleted as i was busy designing the app?

Comment: I added the code back, do you think it will help if i recoded the application? and can it be that the compiler stored irrelevant data that i might have added and deleted as i was busy designing the app?

Comment: @user3350153 I suggest you try getting to the bottom of the problem. This way you'll learn what you did wrong. For starters, try pinpointing the exact location of the problem. Just execute the code line by line and check whether the variables have the expected values.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that. Thanks for your time and patients and help